# Receive and send data through TCP

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

My task is to receive data through TCP connection from a client, and then send the same values back to the client continuously. It's a basic code, but I'll just be sure whether the p1[i] has the same values as p[i] and sends the received data back to the client, since I can't test it before tomorrow. I have just included the communication part with the client, not the connection establishing.

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    WSADATA wsa;
    SOCKET s , new_socket;
    struct sockaddr_in server , client;
    int c;
    char iResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    char sendbuf [DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int sendbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    unsigned int i; 
    uint8_t* p;
    uint8_t* p1;
    int x=0;
    int q=0;
    size_t len;

    p = (uint8_t*)recvbuf;
    len= iResult/sizeof(uint8_t);

    do
    {
        iResult = recv( new_socket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        {
            for(i=0; i<len; i++)
            {
                p[i];
            }       
        }
        if( iResult == 0 ) 
        {
            wprintf(L"Connection closed\n");
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(L"recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        }
    }
    while(iResult > 0 );

    // Send uint8_t back data to client
    p1 = (uint8_t*)sendbuf;

    iResult = send(new_socket, sendbuf, sendbuflen, 0);
    {
        for(q=0; q<len; q++)
        {
            p1[q] = p[q];
        }
    }

    return 0;

    closesocket(new_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Does the code send the received data back ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My task is to receive data through TCP connection from a client, and then send the same values back to the client continuously.

That may be your task, but that is not what your code is actually doing.  There are a lot of problems with your code:

1. `iResult` is uninitialized when `len` is assigned, so your loop after `recv()` is invalid.  And the loop itself is useless because it not actually doing anything.
2. `recv()` returns `>0` if bytes are received, `0` on disconnect, and `-1` on error.  You are logging `>0` as an error when it really is not.
3. you are not calling `send()` until after `recv()` has reported an error/disconnect.  You need to move `send()` inside of the receive loop.
4. you are not copying any data from `recvbuf` to `sendbuf` before calling `send()` so you are sending random garbage.  You are copying data from `recvbuf` to `sendbuf` only after `send()` has been called, but you are still using the invalid `len` value that was calculated before `recv()` was called, so now you are potentially trashing random memory.
5. you are calling `return` before calling `closesocket()` or `WSACleanup()`.

If all you want to do is echo any received data for the lifetime of the connection then try this instead:

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    SOCKET new_socket;
    int iResult, len;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    char *p;

    // establish connection ...

    do
    {
        iResult = recv(new_socket, recvbuf, sizeof(recvbuf), 0);
        if( iResult < 0 ) 
        {
            wprintf(L"recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            break;
        }

        if( iResult == 0 ) 
        {
            wprintf(L"Connection closed\n");
            break;
        }

        p = recvbuf;
        len = iResult;

        do
        {
            iResult = send(new_socket, p, len, 0);
            if( iResult <= 0 ) 
            {
                wprintf(L"send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                break;
            }

            p += iResult;
            len -= iResult;
        }
        while( len > 0 );
    }
    while (true);

    closesocket(new_socket);

    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Does the code send the received data back?

No it doesn't, because it sends from a different buffer, and also because it ignores the length returned by the `recv(),` so it can send arbitrary junk.

Most of the code doesn't begin to make sense:

```
for(i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
    p[i];
    }
```

This accomplishes precisely nothing.

```
if( iResult == 0 ) 
  {
        wprintf(L"Connection closed\n");
  }
  else
  {
        wprintf(L"recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
  }
```

You are printing an error message even if `iResult > 0`, which means data was received and there was no error.

```
for(q=0; q<len; q++)
    {
    p1[q] = p[q];
    }
```

Again this accomplishes precisely nothing, because you're doing it just before you exit the method, when all the variables declared in it will disappear anyway.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Why is it a problem to send from a different buffer ?. I followed the procedure from this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @user2292615: You are not copying the received data into the buffer that you are sending. Your send buffer contains random garbage because you never initialize it. There are other problems with your code as well.

Comment: It's not a problem to send data from a second buffer, if there is any data *in* the second buffer. In this case there isn't. Just garbage. You could copy the data from the receive buffer to the send buffer, but why not just send from the receive buffer and save time?